# Send and receive simple JSON message over HTTP

Tags: python, json, http, post, server

I want to send and receive some simple data over HTTP.

Here's the server side:

```
import time
import BaseHTTPServer
import json

HOST_NAME = 'localhost' 
PORT_NUMBER = 9000 

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        print "You've got mail!"
        content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length', 0))
        body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        data = json.loads(body)
        print data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    print time.asctime(), "Server Starts - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, 
PORT_NUMBER)
    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    httpd.server_close()
    print time.asctime(), "Server Stops - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
```

Here's the client side:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://localhost:9000'
data = {
    'date': 'the best day',
    'time': 'the best time',
    'name': 'Janet Smith'
}

r = requests.post(url, json=data)
print r.status_code
print r.json()
```

I'm getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "testSend.py", line 17, in
>
> r = requests.post(url, json=data)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
>   return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
>
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 524, in request
>
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in send
>
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
>
> raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
>
> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
>
> BadStatusLine("''",))

EDIT:
I was originally experiencing a server-side error as well, but looks like the issue might have been with a line of pasted code. I re-indented everything and now it works.

Comment: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined` That error shouldn't be possible with this code.  Are you sure you've posted the code correctly?

Comment: The client error is obvious -- the server isn't running, so the client can't connect.

Comment: @JohnGordon positive that the code is as posted. Could you help me understand the client error? I get the same error when I am able to run the server (commented out the code that was causing server side error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there were several problems:

1. The server side error was due to copy pasting code. I needed to re-indent everything.
2. The client side error was fixed by adding self.send_response(200) to my DO_POST function on the server side
3. Doing #2 introduces a new "cannot decode json" error. This is because the response from the server does not contain a json message. So I just need to comment out the print r.json() line or send a json message on the server side.